# $5$ points on a sphere

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Diffuse $5$ points on a sphere. Prove there is a closed half-sphere that has at least $4$ points on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Connect two of the points on a great circle. By the pigeonhole principle, at least $2$ of the remaining $3$ points lie on the same side - giving a closed hemisphere with at least $4$ of the $5$ points.